# How to select all rows for same value of column?

Tags: mysql

How to select all rows that have the same value in a column?

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE count(mcc) > 1 // total all same of value for column mcc > 1
```

[image]

only 338, 338, 338, 340, 340 etc . Not 330, 316, 334 coz they haven't same values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query:-

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE mcc in (SELECT mcc FROM messages
              GROUP BY mcc
              HAVING COUNT(mcc) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks you for your time!